# Is it possible to query nested objects in Realm with Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, realm

When accessing a nested object with the code below the following exception appears:

> System.NotSupportedException: The left-hand side of the Equal operator must be a direct access to a
>   persisted property in Realm.

However in Objective C it seems that you can somehow query nested objects. Is it planned or are there are solutions to query nested objects in xamarin?

```
Realm.All<Person>().Where(p => p.Name.Firstname == "Test");

public class Person : RealmObject
{
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public PersonName Name { get; set; }
}

public class PersonName : RealmObject
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How did you resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a planned feature. You can keep track of the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/806).

Comment: There is no official workaround. The best solution is going to depend on the nature of your objects and how many you are going to be working with.

Comment: I implemented the workaround [here](https://github.com/Shaddix/realm-dotnet) with example usage described in aforementioned github issue (basically, it's like `realm.All<Owner>().AddLinkQuery(x => x.TopDog.Color, PredicateOperator.Equal, "Black")`). I was actively using that from Feb to Jun on iOS while our project was running. It was dirty, but it worked (it actually did pass the query to underlying c++ engine like in realm-java). Btw, I'm really surprised this issue is still not implemented in C# API, I thought any serious DB work require that :)